# How can i deploy backend only in Magento2

Tags: magento2, backend

Is there a way to deploy `backend` only in magento. As of right now we have Just 2 options available on [Magento2 Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict)

I'm not sure if we have new options came on `2.1.x`, Goal is to save deployment time while i'm only working on `backend` only.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It sounds to me like you're trying to solve a problem on the wrong level. Have you thought about putting the store in maintenance mode but still allowing backend access for your IP? That would render the frontend unusable but the backend would work.

Comment: I'm having some issue in the backend views so for each time i had to run deployment which deploy fronted file as well

Comment: so your goal is to save time because the deployment takes a while?

Comment: yeah right you getting my point

Comment: Why time for deployment is problem for you? Do you deploy to production many times in day? You never should run deployment tool in development!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge what your asking is not possible in Magento2 at the moment. However, since your goal is to save time, here are two options:

- Just don't wait for it to finish deploying. In my experience the backend is always deployed first, so as soon as that is done you can start using it, even while the frontend is still deploying.
- Set your frontend to a different language, but only deploy the language in which your backend is configured. This should trick the system into what you want.

Comment: In my case frontend applied first and then backend ,  Language will not effect as we will have the same language for frontend too.

Comment: sure, in the end you will set the languages that you need, but during development, you could try setting the frontend to a language that you will never use, just until your backend issues are sorted out....